# Using abstract base to implement private parts of a template class?

Tags: c++

When using templates to implement mix-ins (as an alternative to multiple inheritance) there is the problem that all code must be in the header file. I'm thinking of using an abstract base class to get around that problem. Here's a code sample:

```
class Widget
{
public:
    virtual ~Widget() {}
};

// Abstract base class allows to put code in .cpp file.
class AbstractDrawable
{
public:
    virtual ~AbstractDrawable() = 0;

    virtual void draw();

    virtual int getMinimumSize() const;
};

// Drawable mix-in
template<class T>
class Drawable : public T,
                 public AbstractDrawable
{
public:
    virtual ~Drawable() {}

    virtual void draw()
    { AbstractDrawable::draw(); }

    virtual int getMinimumSize() const
    { return AbstractDrawable::getMinimumSize(); }
};

class Image : public Drawable< Widget >
{
};


int main()
{
    Image i;
    i.draw();
    return 0;
}
```

Has anyone walked that road before? Are there any pitfalls that I should be aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem like this will work the way you want it to because you lose the ability to have the behavior of the mixin class depend on its template argument.  That is, if you want to be mixing in functionality that uses static polymorphism or references the class in the template argument, you no longer can do so because the same code will get executed regardless of the template argument.

If your mixing type doesn't depend on the template argument, however, this seems fine.  You might want to make the functions that get mixed in nonvirtual, though, since you can statically determine which functions you're calling (namely, the AbstractDrawable methods).